# How to add a link automatically in a github Pull request using the PR Number in the link

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to add a link to a site in a PR request automatically. The link will include the PR number is there a way to do this when a PR is raised so that it is in the PR description . The link will point to a review app based on the PR number

eg [www.pr-1234.com](http://www.pr-1234.com) where 1234 is the PR number?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the [github workflow context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts) during a workflow run using Github Actions.

To print it, you can for example use a workflow like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  context:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJSON(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
```

In this GITHUB_CONTEXT, you will always have a `github.event` property, which corresponds to:

> The full event webhook payload. You can access individual properties of the event using this context. This object is identical to the webhook payload of the event that triggered the workflow run, and is different for each event. The webhooks for each GitHub Actions event is linked in "[Events that trigger workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows)." For example, for a workflow run triggered by the [`push event`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#push), this object contains the contents of the [push webhook payload](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push).

It is the same behavior for a `pull_request` event

*Obs: here is [a gist](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/e53ec9b6bc783cce184bd1eec263799d) I use as support when I need to check what fields are available on a pull_request event payload*

In the pull request event context, you can access a **pull_request number** by using `github.event.number` in your workflow (or `${{ github.event.number }}`).

Then, you could use an action from the [Github Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=pull+request+comment+) in the same job, to add a comment to the pull request that triggered the workflow. Here is [an action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/comment-pull-request) that could help you doing it (there are others), for example by using `www.pr-${{ github.event.number }}.com` in the action message input.